# Capture frames from webcam

Tags: 14.04, camera

I have a USB webcam that has a frame rate of 30 frames/sec. Is there a command that can be used in the terminal to read these frames and save them while adding a timestamp to each of them? Something like the "cu" command.

**Update:**

After some research, I found that the following command does the job for 1 fps:

```
fswebcam -q -l 1 --fps 1 /home/user/%H-%M-%S.jpeg
```

The issue now is that upon increasing the fps rate, I am not sure how to update the files names accordingly. I tried the following:

```
fswebcam -q -l 1 --fps 30 /home/user/%H-%M-%S-%N.jpeg
```

but this seems not working. (%N is for the nanoseconds).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question but kind of meets it halfway. You can install something like [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/) to record video. You'd have to browse the forums to find or learn how to create a plugin for the timestamp part (I think, I only use it on Windows for gameplay recording)

Comment: The whole point is that I don't want any offline processing.

Comment: @Hamid Looking at the [fswebcam man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/fswebcam.1.html), I tested fswebcam a bit. From what I tried, I couldn't get it to capture more than once a second. Also, %N isn't a valid timestamp variable in strftime, which is what fswebcam uses to get the time for timestamps. [Strftime man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man3/strftime.3.html)